# What options exists to sleep the display?

Tags: 12.04, display, sleep

I want to sleep my display  - **just the display**, not the computer.

I've been looking in Compiz for an option like "*hot corner to sleep display*" - something that I've setup in OSX 10.7.

How can I accomplish something similar in Ubuntu 12.04? (shortcut, command in terminal,... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use compizconfig-settings-manager (in universe) and enable the commands plugin.  Pick a command slot (any number will work) and enter `xset dpms force off` then bind the command to the edge or corner of your choice under the edge bindings tab.

You could also use `gnome-screensaver-command -a` instead of xset to activate the screensaver (blank screen). Use the compiz command plugin to bind to an edge or corner as before.

Comment: Sorry for un-accepting, but I've noticed that this command causes compiz to use 100% CPU while the display is "sleeping". It's not recommended method.

Comment: That's ok, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.  You could conceivable bind the above command to a keyboard shortcut.  It is not as slick, but would accomplish the same thing.  I will check to see if there are any bugs reported against compiz.

Comment: I have thought the same. I thought that having the mouse cursor at the corner might loop trigger the command. But using a shortcut to accomplish the same did not change this behavior.

Comment: the xset command is causing compiz to run at 100? Not the commands plugin?

Comment: The system monitor reports only compiz to have such high CPU usage - right after I see the screen again.

Comment: Could you try a different command?  Could you try `gnome-screensaver-command -a` and see if it is any better?  Also, I had a problem with compiz running at 100% a few days ago, and I don't use this hack.  After an update the problem was solved.

Comment: This seems fine! Thanks again. Please change/add this to your question.